# Specialist sudoku

Tags: knowledge, geography, sudoku

I know y'all want to be generalists or something, but here's a little sudoku for (geography) specialists. Enjoy.

> [image]
>
> ABRAU ⋅ AGANTON ⋅ AKUSEKIJIMA ⋅ <strike>ALICE HOLT</strike> ⋅ ALTENBURG-NOBITZ ⋅ ANJEDIVA ⋅ APULIA ⋅ ASHTAMUDI ⋅ ATTU ⋅ <strike>CAMPO DEL MORO</strike> ⋅ CARLHAUSHÖHE ⋅ CASA DE CAMPO ⋅ CHAMP DE MARS ⋅ <strike>CHANY</strike> ⋅ <strike>CHULMAN NERYUNGRI</strike> ⋅ <strike>CHUSOVSKOYE</strike> ⋅ <strike>COCHIN INT.</strike> ⋅ CROTONE-SANT'ANNA ⋅ GELSENKIRCHEN ⋅ GIARDINI MARGHERITA ⋅ GILA ⋅ GIRONA-COSTA BRAVA ⋅ <strike>GRANDE CASSE</strike> ⋅ GREAT OUSE ⋅ <strike>GROßE LABER</strike> ⋅ <strike>GÜELL</strike> ⋅ <strike>GWYDIR</strike> ⋅ LA FLORIDA ⋅ LAOUZAS ⋅ <strike>LAUVITEL</strike> ⋅ LEIPZIG ⋅ LEMMON ⋅ LOIRE ⋅ LOMOND ⋅ LOUISIANA ⋅ <strike>LUCRINUS</strike> ⋅ MAES-YR-UCHAF ⋅ MAHANADI ⋅ MAJULI ⋅ MÁLAGA ⋅ <strike>MALAGUNI</strike> ⋅ MANZANARES ⋅ MAUNA KEA ⋅ MILAN ⋅ <strike>MOSSÈN COSTA I LLOBERA</strike> ⋅ NAPLES-CAPODICHINO ⋅ <strike>NARMADA</strike> ⋅ <strike>NATURE ET PAYSAGES</strike> ⋅ <strike>NEMADJI</strike> ⋅ NÉOUVIELLE ⋅ NETLEY HEATH ⋅ NORMANDY ⋅ NORTH OSSETIA-ALANIA ⋅ NUREMBERG ⋅ OBERHAUSEN ⋅ ODISHA ⋅ OHIO ⋅ OKINAWA PREFECTURE ⋅ OLDMAN WOOD ⋅ <strike>OMODEO</strike> ⋅ OMSK OBLAST ⋅ <strike>OREGON</strike> ⋅ OSMANABAD (OMN) ⋅ SAGANO BAMBOO ⋅ SAKHALIN ⋅ <strike>SANCTI PETRI</strike> ⋅ SANTERNO ⋅ SHEREMETYEVO ⋅ SHIKOKU ⋅ SOBRETTA ⋅ SOIERNSPITZE ⋅ SPREE ⋅ TADASU NO MORI ⋅ <strike>TAIHEIYO EVERGREEN</strike> ⋅ TIREE ⋅ TOKUSHIMA AWAODORI ⋅ <strike>TOKYO</strike> ⋅ TOM A' CHÒINICH ⋅ <strike>TOMSK</strike> ⋅ TOYAMA ⋅ TRESIDDER

Comment: (geography) specialists or (Google) specialists?

Comment: @ManojKumar A strong Google-fu certainly helps!

Comment: What's the criteria to fill in? I thought a character cannot take the same position of the block in another grid. For eg: C is repeating in Cochin and Chulman. Also G is repeating in bottom right.

Comment: @ManojKumar The criteria are not explicitly specified on purpose. All tags are relevant, though :) If nobody gets it in a day or two I'll add a hint.

Comment: So the category they belong to should not be repetitive? Because Sudoku is like that. So if there is Lake on Top middle, it should not be in another top middle block. Am I getting this right?

Comment: How certain are you about (1) Lessoc and (2) La Florida?

Comment: I was also wondering about LESSOC, as well as TRESSIDER.

Comment: Argh, yeah, I see it now. I'm sorry, Lessoc is wrong. Give me a minute to fix that. Not sure I see the problem with La Florida or Tressider, though?

Comment: I think Tressider should be Tresidder.

Comment: I don't know for sure whether there _is_ a problem with La Florida, but my google-fu is letting me down a bit if there isn't. (My guess: it's fine and the problem is mine.)

Comment: Changed LESSOC to LAOUZAS. Sorry about the dumb mistake there.

Comment: Does the Sudoku have a unique solution? Many items that start with the same letter also have the same geographical categorization (e.g. River).

Comment: @Jens Yes, the puzzle has a unique solution and should be solvable without guessing (unless I've made a mistake, of course). I solved it twice before posting and got the same solution both times, so that's at least somewhat comforting :)

Comment: I find no solution, which I assume means I've miscategorized something. (There are a number of names that correspond to multiple categories, and I didn't by any means prove that the specific way I classified them was the only way to get the numbers right.) Of course, I might also have misunderstood what it means to solve the puzzle, but I'm pretty sure I've got that right.

Comment: (Or, of course, I might have made a copying error somewhere, or the code I'm using to check solutions might be broken, or something. So many possibilities.)

Comment: Incidentally, I found the right La Florida; I'm not sure why I had trouble doing so before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The completed grid:

> ```
> Omsk Oblast         Gelsenkirchen      Shikoku                | Alice Holt        Tresidder          Lauvitel             | Mahanadi           Casa de Campo    Naples-Capodichino
> Nemadji             Manzanares         Ashtamudi              | Chulman Neryungri Okinawa Prefecture Santerno             | Tiree              Grande Casse     Leipzig
> Tom a' Choinich     Loire              Crotone-Sant'Anna      | Majuli            Nuremberg          Guell                | Sagano Bamboo      Oregon           Abrau
> --------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
> Spree               Tokushima Awaodori Neouvielle             | La Florida        Gwydir             Attu                 | Chany              Milan            Odisha
> Malaga              Anjediva           Louisiana              | Omodeo            Sheremetyevo       Carlhaushoehe        | Nature et Paysages Tadasu no Mori   Great Ouse
> Giardini Margherita Chukovskoye        Oldman Wood            | Normandy          Malaguni           Toyama               | Lemmon             Altenburg-Nobitz Sancti Petri
> --------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
> Akusekijima         Ohio               Tomsk                  | Soiernspitze      Lucrinus           Maes-yr-Uchaf        | Girona-Costa Brava Narmada          Champ de Mars
> Cochin Int.         Sobretta           Mossen Costa i Llobera | Gila              Aganton            North Ossetia-Alania | Oberhausen         Lomond           Taiheiyo Evergreen
> Laouzas             Netley Heath       Grosse Laber           | Tokyo             Campo del Moro     Osmanabad (OMN)      | Apulia             Sakhalin         Mauna Kea
> ```

So, first of all,

> we can classify each of our 81 names in three ways: by first letter; by the country where the thing is; and by what sort of thing it is. For some of them there are multiple possible classifications or multiple possible countries; there are a few different ways to pick and choose so that everything is consistent; both Jens and I made plausible but wrong choices, and jafe kindly put us out of our misery in the comments. The correct assignments are below. I hope.

So:

> ALR  ABRAU · karst lake in Russia, spur of Caucasus mountain range, winery, peninsula
>  AIF  AGANTON · tidal island off north coast of Brittany in France
>  AIJ  AKUSEKIJIMA · Japanese island, Tokara group in Satsunan Is. in Kagoshima Prefecture
>  AFK  ALICE HOLT · royal forest in Hampshire, UK, formerly oak, now conifers
>  AAG  ALTENBURG-NOBITZ · airport in Thuringia, near Leipzig, Germany
>  AII  ANJEDIVA · island in Arabian Sea off Canacona in Goa, India; fort
>  ASY  APULIA · region of Italy, southern peninsular section, eastern coast, Adriatic/Ionian/Otranto
>  ALI  ASHTAMUDI · lake in India; Kerala
>  AIU  ATTU · US island, westernmost point of Alaska, in the Near Islands, uninhabited
>  CPS  CAMPO DEL MORO · park in Madrid, Spain; gardens of Royal Palace of Madrid
>  CMG  CARLHAUSHÖHE · mountain in Harz mountain range in Northern Germany
>  CPS  CASA DE CAMPO · park in Madrid, Spain --or-- seaside resort in Dominican Republic
>  CPF  CHAMP DE MARS · park in Paris, France, near Eiffel Tower
>  CLR  CHANY · lake and municipality in Novosibirsk, Russia
>  CAR  CHULMAN NERYUNGRI · airport in Yakutia, Russia
>  CLR  CHUSOVSKOYE · lake in Perm Krai, Russia
>  CAI  COCHIN INT. · airport in Kochi, Kerala, India
>  CAY  CROTONE-SANT'ANNA · airport in Crotone, Calabria, Italy
>  GCG  GELSENKIRCHEN · city, in Westphalia, Germany
>  GPY  GIARDINI MARGHERITA · park in Bologna, Italy
>  GRU  GILA · river in New Mexico, US; some places in Arizona; = Sonoran Desert; mountain range in US
>  GAS  GIRONA-COSTA BRAVA · airport near Girona, Catalonia, Spain
>  GMF  GRANDE CASSE · mountain in Vanoise Massif, Graian Alps, Savoie, France
>  GRK  GREAT OUSE · river in UK
>  GRG  GROßE LABER · river in Bavaria, Germany, tributary of Danube
>  GPS  GÜELL · park in Barcelona, Spain
>  GFK  GWYDIR · forest and castle in Conwy in Snowdonia in Wales, UK
>  LPS  LA FLORIDA · airport in Chile --or-- wetland park in Colombia --or-- US state --or-- commune in Chile; but treating as Spanish, which it apparently must be
>  LLF  LAOUZAS · lake in France
>  LLF  LAUVITEL · lake in Isere department of France
>  LCG  LEIPZIG · city and region in Saxony, Germany
>  LMU  LEMMON · mountain in Arizona, US --or-- various US towns
>  LRF  LOIRE · river in France
>  LLK  LOMOND · lake in Scotland, UK
>  LSU  LOUISIANA · US state; various regions and towns
>  LLY  LUCRINUS · lake in Campania, Southern Italy, near Avernus
>  MFK  MAES-YR-UCHAF · forest in Monmouthshire, Wales, UK
>  MRI  MAHANADI · river in East Central India
>  MII  MAJULI · island in Brahmaputra River in Assam, India
>  MCS  MÁLAGA · airport, province, municipality in Spain
>  MRI  MALAGUNI · river in Khurda, Odisha, India
>  MPS  MANZANARES · river in central Spain
>  MMU  MAUNA KEA · mountain (volcano, site of telescope) in Hawai'i, US
>  MCY  MILAN · city in Italy (airports have other specific names)
>  MPS  MOSSÈN COSTA I LLOBERA · park (botanical garden) in Barcelona, Spain
>  NAY  NAPLES-CAPODICHINO · airport in Naples, Italy
>  NRI  NARMADA · river in central India
>  NPF  NATURE ET PAYSAGES · park (botanical garden) in Gers, France, specializing in carnivorous plants
>  NFU  NEMADJI · river and forest in Minnesota, US
>  NMF  NÉOUVIELLE · mountain group (massif) in Pyrenees, France --or-- park (nature reserve) there
>  NFK  NETLEY HEATH · forest in Surrey, England, UK
>  NSF  NORMANDY · region of France (what else?)
>  NSR  NORTH OSSETIA-ALANIA · republic in Russia
>  NCG  NUREMBERG · city in Germany
>  OCG  OBERHAUSEN · city in Germany
>  OSI  ODISHA · state in India
>  OSU  OHIO · state in US
>  OSJ  OKINAWA PREFECTURE · prefecture in Japan
>  OFK  OLDMAN WOOD · forest in Scotland, UK
>  OLY  OMODEO · artificial lake in Sardinia, Italy
>  OSR  OMSK OBLAST · federal subject of Russia
>  OSU  OREGON · state in US
>  OAI  OSMANABAD (OMN) · airport in Maharashtra, India
>  SFJ  SAGANO BAMBOO · forest in Kyoto, Japan
>  SIR  SAKHALIN · island in Russia
>  SIS  SANCTI PETRI · island in Cadiz, Spain
>  SRY  SANTERNO · river in Romagna, Northern Italy
>  SAR  SHEREMETYEVO · airport in Moscow, Russia
>  SIJ  SHIKOKU · island of Japan
>  SMY  SOBRETTA · mountain in Lombardy, Italy
>  SMG  SOIERNSPITZE · mountain in Soiern Group, Bavaria, Germany
>  SRG  SPREE · river in Saxony, Brandenburg & Berlin, Germany and Czech Republic
>  TFJ  TADASU NO MORI · forest in Kyoto, Japan
>  TFJ  TAIHEIYO EVERGREEN · forest region in Japan
>  TIK  TIREE · island and airport in Hebrides, Scotland, UK
>  TAJ  TOKUSHIMA AWAODORI · airport in Japan
>  TCJ  TOKYO · city in Japan
>  TMK  TOM A' CHÒINICH · mountain in Scotland, UK
>  TCR  TOMSK · city and oblast in Russia
>  TCJ  TOYAMA · city and prefecture in Japan
>  TMU  TRESSIDER · misspelt mountain in Yosemite, California, US

Here

> we have all those place names, in their originally-given alphabetical order, one per line; the three-letter code at the start of each line consists of (1) the first letter of the place name, (2) the kind of place it is (**A**irport, **C**ity, **F**orest or wood, **I**sland, **L**ake, **M**ountain, massif, etc., **P**ark or gardens, **R**iver, **S**tate, prefecture, etc.), and (3) what country it's in (**F**rance, **G**ermany, **I**ndia, **J**apan, the United **K**ingdom, **R**ussia, **S**pain, the **U**nited States, Ital**Y**). My annotations mention other possibilities for some of these places, and in fact in one instance they *fail* to mention what jafe has now revealed was intended as the correct assignment :-).

And now

> it seems that the obvious thing to try to do is to put the places into the grid so that no row, column or 3x3 box contains two with the same initial letter, the same feature-type, or the same country.

It's OK that

> some (letter, feature, country) triples are repeated, because in each case one of the repeated ones is already in the grid so it should be possible to disambiguate them. (And it turns out that it is.)

Here are

> the three component sudoku (initial letters, place-types, countries):
>
> ```
> O G S | A T L | M C N    S C I | F M L | R P A    R G J | K U F | I S Y
> N M A | C O S | T G L    F P L | A S R | I M C    U S I | R J Y | K F G
> T L C | M N G | S O A    M R A | I C P | F S L    K F Y | I G S | J U R
> ------+-------+------    ------+-------+------    ------+-------+------
> S T N | L G A | C M O    R A M | P F I | L C S    G J F | S K U | R Y I
> M A L | O S C | N T G    C I S | L A M | P F R    S I U | Y R G | F J K
> G C O | N M T | L A S    P L F | S R C | M A I    Y R K | F I J | U G S
> ------+-------+------    ------+-------+------    ------+-------+------
> A O T | S L M | G N C    I S C | M L F | A R P    J U R | G Y K | S I F
> C S M | G A N | O L T    A M P | R I S | C L F    I Y S | U F R | G K J
> L N G | T C O | A S M    L F R | C P A | S I M    F K G | J S I | Y R U
> ```

Credit where due:

> Jens found essentially all the same geographical information as I did, and his assignments were a little closer to the intended ones than mine. He could have done the last step just as easily as me. (Our work was independent, though.) Go upvote something of his if you liked this.

Comment: Given your observation that having a few "triplets" doesn't matter if  one of them is already in the grid (should have seen this myself), I suspect we are on the right track. It only remains to fiddle the geographical assignments correctly. As you say, a rather tedious endeavour. ;)

Comment: I'm tempted to write a program to do it. And yes, I'd be extremely surprised if this weren't the right track. The only reason I haven't written the program already is the thought that maybe jafe intended the assignments to be "obvious" and didn't intend solvers to have to try lots of possibilities and attempt to solve the sudokoid for each one, which does seem like a lot of fairly unrewarding work. Maybe there's something clever one can do to reduce it, though it's not clear what.

Comment: Yep, you're on the right track. This is definitely meant to be human-solvable and not require any deep try-this-if-not-then-roll-back chains, though. I commented about the intended labellings under Jens's answer.

Comment: OK, very solvable with the intended labellings :-).

Comment: All correct, nice work! Sorry about the ambiguity headaches, I did mean to leave some degree of freedom there but it turned out to be too much because I didn't check carefully enough. There are a lot of places in the world with the same name!

Answer (score 5):

**Partial answer**

I hesitate to call this a partial answer as it more of lack-of-progress report, but I do have at least one observation which must be relevant.

From the OP we see that there are 81 words divided into groups of 9 words starting with one of the letters A, C, G, L, M, N, O, S, T. Assuming the starting letters are relevant for the sudoku, and given that the solution is unique, we have the problem of which e.g. A word to place in a spot requiring an A word. There must be another selection criteria.

I therefore looked at what type of "thing" each word was. After a bit of squeezing and tucking (some words fit more than one category) I managed to fit them into one of 9 categories, with 9 in each.

> [image]

The problem though, is that some words starting with the same letter also have the same  categorization. How then to chose?

I then looked at

> which countries each word was located in. Turns out the words are neatly divided into 9 words in each of 9 countries!

Expanding my table above, we have

> [image]

However, again we have the problem that

> some words starting with same letter are also from the same country. Again, how to chose?

And even if we decide that all three categorizations are relevant, we have several cases where all three are the same, e.g.

> CAMPO DEL MORO and CASA DE CAMPO both start with the letter C, are both in Spain and are both parks.

So, to sum up:

> The observation that all words can be neatly divided between 9 countries cannot be a coincidence. Whether the geograhical categorization is relevant is debateable, but it is striking that such a categorization is possible. Perhaps there is a fourth way to categorize?

Comment: Heh. I am just in the middle of writing up a similar lack-of-progress report. It will be interesting to compare your assignments with mine.

Comment: (On the one I'm most doubtful about, we agree.)

Comment: @Gareth I'm also looking forward to your lack-of-progress report!

Comment: Aha, we do have some differences. Give me a couple of minutes and I'll try it out with your choices...

Comment: Ha, I have a mistranscription in mine, which probably explains why I also have a different choice in one place. [EDITED to add:] No, wait, it's not a mistranscription, just a different legitimate choice, sorry.

Comment: OK, we differ by a "3-cycle".

Comment: Unfortunately I have no more success solving with yours than with mine. I'll add a note to that effect in my own lack-of-progress report.

Comment: You're definitely on the right track. I may have underestimated how many options there are for some of these! In particular, when there's a Wikipedia page with a non-disambiguated title, I didn't check the disambiguation pages to see what other possibilities there were. Some like Gila seem to have a lot more meanings than I assumed as well. Your labellings are the same as intended except for Gila (river intended), Gwydir (forest) and Manzanares (park). (Pinging @GarethMcCaughan as well)